# Matomo iframe widgets report "For embedding widgets super user token auths are not allowed" but auth token is read-only

Tags: matomo

We have started using Matomo for analytics on some of our web sites.

We're experimenting with adding iframe widgets and graphs into particular parts of our Web app for certain authorised users. To do this we set up a read-only user in Matomo, and created an api auth key for it. We use this key as part of the request URL for the Matomo widgets.

Despite this, it looks like it's using my browser cookie to override the api auth key. When logged in to Matomo and trying to view the analytics, I get the following message:

```
This user has super user access. For embedding widgets super user token auths are not allowed.
```

To get rid of this message I have to log out of the Matomo dashboard first. Then the widgets work fine, using the api auth key.

This isn't really ideal. Is there any way to have it be forced to use the key in the URL and not what's in my cookie or browser?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it may be a bug in Matomo maybe? If you can reproduce this, then maybe create a bug report (with steps to reproduce) on the issue tracker at https://www.github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it does look like a bug. I've reported it and someone pointed out that it's a duplicate and reported last month.